# Round Results Up or to Even

Tags: formatting

In 20+ years of research, I believed rounding of results should follow the "round up at 0.5" rule, while internal rounding during computation may follow other rules such as "round to even" that are supposed to reduce cumulative errors. However, I just learned that my favourite programming language's string format '%.2f' uses "round to even", e.g.

```
$ python
Python 3.6.15 (default, Sep 23 2021, 15:41:43) [GCC] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> '%.2f' %0.125
'0.12'
>>> '%.2f' %0.375
'0.38'
```

I wrote a little function frac2decimal(n,d,precision=2) that prints fractions n/d as decimal with "round up at .5" with configurable number of places. In the absence of policies on this matter at my institution and from my publisher, should I use it in future or stick with "round to even"?

Related:

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218821/round-to-even-rule
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding

Comment: Your post does not have a question mark :-)

Comment: Thanks. "Should I" is a question, just used the wrong punctuation. Fixing...

Comment: "Stick with round to even" is not as simple as continuing to use "%.2f" as the actual rounding method used is platform-dependent. One would have to move to a way of rounding numbers that allows to specify the method, e.g. using Python's "decimal" module. With no clear preference in the community (answers so far), I doesn't matter which method it is. What matters is that the same method will be applied when someone else runs my software again in a replication study as I need them to get the exact same results so that don't say they couldn't replicate my results.

Comment: Do you have an actual example in your field where someone says they "weren't able to replicate results" based on being off by a rounding error (that is, one person reports 72.8% and someone else finds 72.7% and states "these results couldn't be replicated"), or is this an imagined scenario?

Comment: @BryanKrause No, I've only read a small number of replication papers. It's also unlikely that rounding is different in current replications where the compute platform is highly similar (NVIDIA GPUs, CUDA, x86_64 CPUs, Linux, GNU C Library, CPython). Over time, however, platforms change, differences become more likely and once a different rounding method has become common we should see a lot of cases because the results are usually fractions with a round denominator, e.g. 20000, causing a lot more ties in rounding than expected with random numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Some considerations:

1. If it matters, be explicit about what you did.
2. If it matters (e.g., the distinction between .12 and .13 is important), you should be reporting more than 2 decimal points. If your measurements are not sufficiently precise to support a third decimal point, then you don't actually have enough precision for it to matter.
3. For most "real data" contexts with continuous computations, the probability of ever observing a number ending in exactly "5" down to machine precision is vanishingly small. Consider other representations for data where you'll be e.g. dividing integers by integers: does the original integer tell you more than the ratio? For example, if 3/16 responders in your survey prefer "round to even" over "round up at 0.5", you probably shouldn't be reporting that as 18.75%, 18.8%, or 19% - all those numbers imply far more precision in measurement than you actually have. Just report 3/16 or 3 out of 16.
4. For observed data that are already rounded by the limits of precision of some technique that gives data to 3 decimal places, for example, 0.12 and 0.13 are exactly the same number. You should always use the full data (e.g. 0.125) for all computations, and only round for the very last step (typically, for display).

Comment: Re 3: In my current work, the probability is 7.14%. I report accuracy of a classifier on a test set of size 2800 with 3 significant digits, e.g. 72.8% for 2037/2800 = 0.7275.

Comment: @JoachimWagner This is valid, but, like Bryan said, almost certainly insignificant. Would your classifier performance be considered that different if it was 2038/2800 instead? While there is no shortage of papers on hair splitting with relatively small datasets, two NN architectures, one giving 72.8% accuracy and another 74% accuracy on a dataset of size 2800 are basically the same (but 3 significant digits are standard in the field). Class balance alone can upset this value far more than measly .1%. Also also, f'{accuracy:.1%}' for 3.6+ ;).

Comment: @Lodinn: I know it is insignificant in the sense that the choice of rounding method does not misrepresent results. If the choice was significant it would be more appropriate to simply display an additional digit. However, in my field, there is the expectation to be able to replicate results exactly as the results are the output of a computer program with exactly described inputs. Leaving the rounding method to default settings of a compute platform is not desirable in this context.

Comment: @JoachimWagner If your field considers "replication" to be getting exactly 2037/2800 and 2038/2800 is "not replicating", you need to report 2037/2800, not 72.8% or 72.7%, each of which represents multiple different numbers, some of which are more different than 2037 vs 2038. If you choose to also contextualize this number as being equivalent to 72.8% or 72.7%, that's okay. If you think the way you round is important, you can state the rounding method that you used. It's irrelevant whether this is based on a default setting.

Comment: @BryanKrause The default setting is that the rounding method is undefined, i.e. the method can be different on different computer systems. To make the results replicable while following the standard practice in my field of reporting percentages rather than fractions with arbitrary denominators, I need to write code to select a specific rounding method. In my question, I try to find out which rounding method will be the best choice as I need to pick one.

Comment: @JoachimWagner I don't know how to be more clear: **write in your paper what method you used**, whether it's a method you "select" or something chosen for you by software. Just write what you used. No need to write code if your choice is default, no need to worry so much about which to choose. Write what was used. Include the full numbers someplace, either on the manuscript or a data supplement.

Comment: @BryanKrause Showing the exact numbers in the appendix is not a solution unless it becomes widely known that replication studies must compare against those instead of the rounded numbers in the main paper. I see 3 workarounds: (a) write the released code such that it does not display rounded numbers at all (and pretend I created all result tables manually), (b) add `assert '%.2f' %(1/8) == '0.12' and '%.2f' %(3/8) == '0.38'` to any code that prints rounded results (and a comment what it means if this fails), or (c) use my own rounding function.

Comment: @JoachimWagner It's your paper, do what you want, but then why bother asking here? I think your three workarounds are silly compared to 1) including your complete results in a data appendix and 2) writing the sentence in your methods section "Approximate results are displayed using 'round-to-even' method."

Comment: @BryanKrause You ignore the reality of not being the most senior author of the paper: My strong push for including such as sentence will be overruled as being way too much detail. Re "Why bother asking here", workaround "c" motivates the question I asked as it requires me to pick a rounding method. The purpose of the question is to get a sense of what experts on rounding of research results think is the preferred method.

Comment: @JoachimWagner If that sentence is too much detail for the senior author (have you actually asked or just assumed?), then I'd conclude that your concerns about rounding overall are also completely unimportant to them, and that you're imagining some issue with "non-replication" that is not actually an issue. That's the whole point of my answer: **if it matters** do these things. Is your senior author convinced it matters? If not, then this is all moot.

Comment: @BryanKrause Thanks to your questions and suggestions, I've come to 3 solutions 4 comments above that satisfy both the reproducibility concern and the "too much detail" concern.

Comment: @JoachimWagner I think those are terrible ideas, especially those that add hidden complexity to your code and workflow. A) doesn't solve anything, B) is terrible practice if you literally mean adding specific code to handle those two cases, it makes your code act differently with different parameters that don't give those precise results and makes it non-portable, and C) adds completely unnecessary complexity and you certainly shouldn't do it without also explaining in your paper they this is what you've done, which would take just as much explanation/detail as any of my suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

How you treat round-off depends on context. There is no "one size" rule that works for any possible type of result.

What you should be doing is [uncertainty analysis.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_analysis) Any given data point will have some degree of accuracy. You *urgently* need to record this information and evaluate how it affects the results you report. If you do not then you leave yourself open to severe criticism of any calculations you perform with the data, even to the point of your conclusions being entirely invalid.

Just a trivial example: If you use a ruler to measure a distance, the usual rule is the accuracy is +/- half the smallest division. So if the ruler is divided into mm, then your uncertainty is +/- 0.5 mm. This will then contribute to the uncertainty in any calculation you perform with this measurement.

For other types of data there will be other types of accuracy or uncertainty. Some times it is +/- some value or percentage. Sometimes it is statistical, such as randomly selecting some sub-set from a population in trying to represent the whole population, such as a survey. Sometimes it is due to systematic effects such as in medical tests that can give false positives or false negatives.

In each case you must include this degree of uncertainty in the measurement when you perform calculations. This is a very large topic with huge amounts of discussion. My favorite method (when it is applicable) is [Monte Carlo.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) There are many valid methods.

But it is very high priority to include a calculation of the accuracy of the result based on the accuracy of the data that is used, and the nature of the calculation.

Comment: Suppose I have done all that. For reporting the relevant final statistics, what rounding method should I employ?

Comment: It depends on the accuracy of the final result, and what form they take. Rounding may not be appropriate at all. This is a *HUGE* subject, entire text books are written on it.  The wiki link is a place to dip your toe.